# How do i find if a positive integer is prime or not?

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, lambda, parameters

Am very new to the C# language and i have been working on this program to find a positive integer is a prime or not. what am i doing wrong and how do i accomplish that. thank you in advance

```
 static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    if (FindPrime(47)) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Prime"); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Not Prime"); 
    } 
    Console.readLine(); 
}   
internal static bool FindPrime(int number) 
{ 
    if (number == 1) return false; 
    if (number == 2) return true; 
    if (number % 2 != 0) return false; 
     Var SquareRoot = (int)Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(number)); 
     for (int i = 3; i <= squareRoot; i += 2) 
    { 
        if (number % i == 0) return false; 
    } 
     return true; 
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I guess, for one thing, you've written `Var`, with a capital V, which isn't correct.

Comment: And "SquareRoot" (capital S) and "squareRoot" (lowercase s) are different variables. Casing is important!

Comment: `if (number % 2 != 0) return false;`. there's your mistake. you want `==` there. VTC because that counts as typo. _which you could have discovered by stepping through your code with the debugger_

Comment: when i run the program in my console it returns nothing and as i said i am very new to this programing language , if knew every things i wouldn't ask ?

Comment: No, you are not expected to know everything, but help us help you by providing as many relevant details as possible. If your program runs, it is not the posted one. But it does seem you are nearly there

Comment: Thank you so much @HansKeﬆing

Comment: @AbuGodda your error was a _simple typo_. not at all relevant to the language in use. and about the numerous syntax errors? your _compiler_ would've given you detailed errors, telling you what is wrong and where.

Comment: Okay thank you and will do my best the next time !

Comment: Sorry i know it was dumb and stupid questions, am sorry to the community !

Comment: @AbuGodda - It's not a dumb and stupid question. You've gained some experience on what to ask, how to ask, and how to debug. That made it a worthwhile question - for you. What matters is if you learn from it moving forward.

Comment: Thank you @Enigmativity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a wikipedia explaining the nature of prime numbers. Check it out.

I have done the same project, in python, and what I did there is save the known prime numbers in a variable and check the current number against all the known prime numbers.

ei.

```
a) prime_number = [2]
3 % 2 != 0 => Add to prime_number

b) prime_number = [2, 3]
4 % 2 == 0 => Not a prime number, go to next number

c) prime_number = [2, 3]
5 % 2 != 0 => Test against other prime numbers
5 % 3 != 0 => Add to prime number

d) prime_number = [2, 3, 5]
6 % 2 == 0 => Not a prime number, go to next number
```

So the prime_number variable grows in size.

Comment: the algorithm in question was perfectly fine. the _problem_ was only a typographical error.